# What should I do with an old thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

I recently had a security system installed which also included a replacement thermostat. Should I just throw this old one in the trash?

[image]

Comment: Cheap digital thermostats can be had for under $20 if you ever needed one again, so it's your call to decide if it's worth hanging on to. Personally I'd get rid of it. FYI, Best Buy takes a ton of electronics and appliances for free recycling. I bet they would take a thermostat.

Comment: Its not like it has a mercury switch to worry about.  Send those to me ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your security system is monitored for a monthly fee I would save it. There is the possibility that it won't function if the service is terminated. If a year from now you decide you no longer want the service you may be in need of a new thermostat. Although it appears to be relatively new verify it doesn't contain mercury, even if it doesn't try to recycle it when you do throw it out.